# How do you orientate a large dataframe in R according to the values in different columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I'am new in R, I have a big dataframe (lot of columns).

I would like to orientate my dataframe according to the values (between 8 and -8) of several columns (Valeur1, Valeur2 and Valeur3) on the basis of differents clusters (rows) of an another column (Clusters).

Here's an example of a part of my table:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Valeur1 = c("-0.02", "-7.1", "4.4", "1.1", "7.9", "0.3","4.7","0.2"),
  Valeur2 = c("-0.05", "-3.2", "4.1", "1.0", "7.1", "0.1","2.1","1.5"),
  Valeur3 = c("8.0", "2.4", "1.4", "1.5", "7.2", "-1.2","3.1","6.2"),
  Clusters = c("1","1","2","3","3","3","1","2"))
```

I would like to orientate it like :

```
data2 <- data.frame(
  Valeur1 = c("-0.02", "4.7", "-7.1", "0.2", "4.4", "7.9","1.1","0.3"),
  Valeur2 = c("-0.05", "2.1", "-3.2", "1.5", "4.1", "7.1","1.0","0.1"),
  Valeur3 = c("8.0", "3.1", "2.4", "6.2", "1.4", "7.2","1.5","-1.2"),
  Clusters = c("1","1","1","2","2","3","3","3"))
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
data2 <- data %>% arrange(Clusters, desc(Valeur3))
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't orientate my rows according to the values

Comment: I think I got what you meant. Updated my response accordingly. What do you say?